# Cycle time calculation in TFS with a data warehouse query

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

Moved from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/193204/cycle-time-calculation-in-tfs-with-a-data-warehouse-query).

This is a simple code to extract [cycle time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/dashboards/cumulative-flow-cycle-lead-time-guidance?view=vsts#lead-time-versus-cycle-time) per project team from Team Foundation Server [data warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sql-reports/components-data-warehouse?toc=%2Fvsts%2Freport%2Fsql-reports%2Ftoc.json&%3Bbc=%2Fvsts%2Freport%2Fsql-reports%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=tfs-2018).

Here is the relationships of tables in data warehouse:
[image: Work Item History tables]

We use Sql Server 2014 with TFS 2018.

I'm not an SQL expert. Is this a good SQL code? If not, how could I improve this query to do less work?

```
Declare @from date;
Declare @initial_state nvarchar(256);
Declare @final_state nvarchar(256);

Set @from = DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE());
Set @initial_state = 'Committed';
Set @final_state = 'Done';

With wi As (
    Select TeamProjectSK, System_Id, System_State, System_ChangedDate, System_WorkItemType
      From [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[DimWorkItem]
      Where 
            System_WorkItemType in ('Bug', 'Product Backlog Item')
            and System_ChangedDate >= @from
            and System_State in (@initial_state, @final_state)
)
Select P.ProjectPath, C.[Cycle Time]
    From DimTeamProject P
    inner join (
        Select D.TeamProjectSK, Avg(D.Duration) [Cycle Time]
            From (
                Select w1.TeamProjectSK, w1.System_Id, DateDiff(day, w1.ChangedDate, w2.ChangedDate) as Duration
                    From (
                        Select TeamProjectSK, System_Id, Min(System_ChangedDate) ChangedDate
                            From wi
                            Group By TeamProjectSK, System_Id, System_State
                            Having System_State=@initial_state
                    ) w1
                    inner join (
                        Select TeamProjectSK, System_Id, Max(System_ChangedDate) ChangedDate
                            From wi
                            Group By TeamProjectSK, System_Id, System_State
                            Having System_State=@final_state
                    ) w2
                    On w1.System_Id=w2.System_Id
        ) D
        Group By D.TeamProjectSK
    ) C
    On C.TeamProjectSK=P.ProjectNodeSK
```

You could find this code [here](https://gist.github.com/evakili/708021d98b915a8563ebf69b7e22d014).

Comment: I suggest you add your SQL Server version. Also give table definition with sample data and possible query plan.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide I've added some info.